# Swift Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'

Tags: swift, optional-binding

I have this following code in my swift project

```
if let availabeDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone,
.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices {

            captureDevice = availabeDevices.first
        }
```

When i run this code it gives me an error on if line that reads:

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'
```

I tried adding `?` after `.devices`,but that gave this error:

```
Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type '[AVCaptureDevice]'
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below lines.

```
if let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone, .builtInWideAngleCamera], 
mediaType: AVMediaType.video, 
position: .back).devices.first {
            self.captureDevice = captureDevice
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Explaining your error here:

You are getting error because `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices` returns `[AVCaptureDevice]` which is not `Optional` and if you want to use `if let` then `RHS` should be always `Optional`.

if you want to get rid of this error you need to make `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices` as `Optional` by adding `as? [AVCaptureDevice]` at the end of it.

And your code will be:

```
if let availabeDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInMicrophone,
                                                                            .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices as? [AVCaptureDevice] {

    let captureDevice = availabeDevices.first
}
```